# Quarkus with camel and TIBCO EMS

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus, tibco, ems

I want to build quarkus application using Apache Camel and TIBCO EMS. However, when i am trying to create a connection factory for TIBCO EMS version 8.4, it doesn't seem to be compatible with my quarkus version. Can you suggest the correct quarkus version to use with TIBCO EMS.
Also, is it possible to use Quarkus 3.x version but javax based ConnectionFactory here ? If so, then how can i do it ?

The below is my pom.xml file

```xml
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>code-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>

        <quarkus.platform.version>3.2.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <tibco-ems.version>8.4</tibco-ems.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-camel-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-log</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-direct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-timer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TIBCO EMS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco.ems</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
            <version>${tibco-ems.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Camel TIBCO EMS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- RabbitMQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-spring-rabbitmq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <native.image.path>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The below is my code:

```java
package routes;
    
import config.TibcoEmsConfiguration;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SendMessageToEMS extends RouteBuilder {

    @Inject
    TibcoEmsConfiguration tibcoEmsConfiguration;

    // Produce the ConnectionFactory using the Jakarta annotation
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        return tibcoEmsConfiguration.jmsConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // Configure the JMS component using the produced ConnectionFactory
        getContext().addComponent("jms",
                JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge((jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory) jmsConnectionFactory()));

        from("jms:queue:myQueue")
                .log("Received message in TIBCO EMS: ${body}")
                .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/myExchange?queue=rabbitQueue&autoDelete=false&durable=false");

        from("timer:myTimer?period=5000")
                .setBody(simple("Hello from Quarkus Camel 1"))
                .to("jms:queue:myQueue");
    }
}
```

Here, at `getContext.addComponent` : i am getting an error as TibjmsConnectionFactory belongs to javax namespace but quarkus is using jakarta namespace.
I tried to downgrade quarkus versions but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I assume the samples are mixed in the question. Quarkus 1.13.7 is definitely is on javax namespace. But the pom.xml seems generated for Quarkus 2.x even 3.x. Based on the error message the application using Quarkus 3.x instead of 1.13.7.  So please update the question which contains the real reproductible example. 
After that choose a namespace. Quarkus 2.x and Tibco 8.4 is for javax and Quarkus 3.x and Tibco 10.2 support jakarta.

Comment: Thanks, i generated a new project with quarkus version 2.16.8.Final and tibco ems 8.4. It worked !!

Comment: is it possible to use Quarkus 3.x version but javax based ConnectionFactory here ? If so, then how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using such old TIBCO EMS client version. The TIBCO EMS Client is downward compatible. So you can use the 10.x client to speak with a 8.4 server. 10.x client supports Jakarta as well as Quarkus 3.x.